# Preload HTML from within Javascript file, into the DOM, but don't execute

Tags: javascript, html

Im creating a simple JS game, which will run in the browser and will pull the files directly from the pc. Because of this needed to make a workaround the "Cross-origin" error, which went smoothly, I put all the HTML within a JS and loaded the JS from the  tag in the index.html. Everything was going smoothly so far.

You click "press any key to continue" -> but then next you click "New Game" and you get event listener error "can't set property of null". Which i don't understand how it happens, because the element is already in the "DOM" , the css could pick it up, but the event listener could not? So i tried moving all scripts on top, rearranging stuff, nothing worked. Pre-loading all HTML into the index.html, without executing it will definitely work, but how can i achieve this exactly? My Configuration atm is:

- index.html (root folder)
- /components/main_menu.js
- /components/character_creation.js

```js
function MainMenu()
{/*
<div id="mm_wrapper_grid">
 <div id="mm_subgrid1">
  
 </div>
 <div id="mm_subgrid2">
  <div id="mm_subgrid2_image"></div>
  <div id="mm_new_game"><p id="mm_new_game_p" class="grow">New Game<p></div>
  <div id="mm_load_game"><p id="mm_load_game_p" class="grow">Load Game</p></div>
  <div id="mm_options"><p id="mm_options_p" class="grow">Options</p></div>
  <div id="mm_credits"><p id="mm_credits_p" class="grow">Credits</p></div>
 </div>
</div>
*/}

function CharacterCreation()
{/*
<div> Character Creation test
</div>
*/}
```

```html
<div id ="game">
 <div id="loading_screen">Press Any Key To Continue</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("loading_screen").addEventListener("click", function() {callback("game", MainMenu)});
document.getElementById("mm_new_game_p").addEventListener("click", function() {callback("game", CharacterCreation)});
  
function callback(arg1, func)
{
 var html = func.toString();
 var htmlstart = html.indexOf('/*');
 var htmlend = html.lastIndexOf('*/');
 var html = html.substr(htmlstart+2, htmlend-htmlstart-2);
 document.getElementById(arg1).innerHTML = html;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you allow cross origin loading from your server?

Comment: the requirement is to do it without a server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the problem because you are trying to add the second listener for `getElementById("mm_new_game_p")` when this element doesn't exist on the page. I suggest you to add the follwing line of code to make sure, that it's true:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("loading_screen").addEventListener("click", function() {callback("game", MainMenu)});

console.log('#mm_new_game_p', document.getElementById("mm_new_game_p"));

document.getElementById("mm_new_game_p").addEventListener("click", function() {callback("game", CharacterCreation)});

...
```

You have to add this listener after this element will be created (after calling of MainMenu() function).

---

To tell the truth, I can see such storing of html templates in js functions for the first time. It's hard to support your code and I've modified it a little bit below. This is not the best way to implement it, but my goal is show you a solution based on your code. What you can see here:

- all the templates for pages are in html (not in JS);
- you can add listeners from html code using HTML attribute `onclick` - and in this case you can be sure, that element exists on the page.

If you want to add listeners from JS, than you have to create own functions for each pages which you have and after HTML template of a page will be added to `#game` container you will need to create event listeners for the buttons which are on the created page.

```js
openPage("game", "loading_screen");

function openPage(parentDOMElementId, name) {
  console.log('openPage:', name);
  var pageHtml = document.getElementById("page_" + name).outerHTML;
  document.getElementById(parentDOMElementId).innerHTML = pageHtml;
}
```

```html
<div id="game"></div>

<div class="templates" style="visibility: hidden;">

  <div id="page_loading_screen" onclick="openPage('game', 'main_menu')">
    Press Any Key To Continue
  </div>

  <div id="page_main_menu">
    <div id="mm_subgrid1">

    </div>
    <div id="mm_subgrid2">
      <div id="mm_subgrid2_image"></div>
      <div id="mm_new_game">
        <p id="mm_new_game_p" class="grow" onclick="openPage('game', 'character_creation')">New Game
          <p>
      </div>
      <div id="mm_load_game">
        <p id="mm_load_game_p" class="grow">Load Game</p>
      </div>
      <div id="mm_options">
        <p id="mm_options_p" class="grow">Options</p>
      </div>
      <div id="mm_credits">
        <p id="mm_credits_p" class="grow">Credits</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="page_character_creation">
    Character Creation test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried your way and it didn't work for me. I also tried to put the event listener into the MainMenu.js file at the bottom and that did not work as well. Next i tried to make a separate function which would execute after MainMenu.js and that did not work as well. I wonder why CSS pick ups the DOM from the html inside the js files, but the event listeners won't.

Comment: @ScarletQueen Do not compare JS and CSS. They have different mechanisms. You just need to understand, that at the beginning you have empty HTML document in your browser, after that on the page appears your HTML code (`#game` container) and browser runs your JS script where you are trying to add listeners, but the page doesn't have these items in DOM, because there is only `#game` container. And only after you add an element to DOM you can find element by ID and add a listener to it.

Comment: You are absolutely right Max, thank you. It seems like the element is not in the DOM. Your way works like a charm. Also it seems that my way is working as well if i put onclick inline event instead of event listener (despite that both are in the JS file). About the code.. it really will be hard to support the code. Do you have another idea how i can maybe load html files from another folder without getting Cross Origin error, and without a server?. If there is another solution i am willing to try. ATM im happy, this works, but you are right, this approach could easily become spaghetti code. :D

Comment: @ScarletQueen 1. Could you please describe your level and experience in HTML+JS? I need it to know what I can advice. The best way for such app will be to use a MVC framework.
2. I'm not fully understand where you can have problems with cross origin. How you run the code? Just open HTML page in browser? It will be better if you can show your code, for example on github or send to me in an archive.